# Application of Latin Squares

Tags: latin-square

There are 36 officers, six officers of six different ranks in each of 6 regiments. Find an arrangement of the 36 officers in a $6\times 6$ square formation such that each row and each column contains one and only one officer from each regiment of each rank. (from Euler).
Dear math stack exchange family, can you help me interpreting this word problem in Latin squares?

Comment: The ranks, when numbered 1 thru 6, form a Latin square. As do the regiments. Furthermore, because each regiment sends in exactly one office of each rank, the two Latin squares must be orthogonal (=MOLS)

Comment: And see for example [here](http://www.ams.org/publicoutreach/feature-column/fcarc-latinii1) for discussion on the impossibility to place the officers as required. The puzzle is famous.